# How can I disable the terminal statusline in gVim?

Tags: terminal, autocmd, statusline

I want to disable the terminal `statusline` in gVim as it seems quite useless and I usually have the windows at a relatively small size when using gVim, so it takes up too much space.

I've tried quite a few things, like this:

```
" Disable statusline in gvim terminal window
if has('gui_running')
  augroup TerminalStatusline
    autocmd!
    autocmd TermOpen * setlocal laststatus=0
    autocmd TermClose * setlocal laststatus=2
  augroup END
endif
```

This results in an error on startup:

```
E216: No such group or event TermOpen * setlocal laststatus=0
```

Even if it didn't error, I don't think it would have done what I wanted anyway, as the `statusline` on other windows would also be disabled until I closed the terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This disables the distracting and unpleasant terminal statusline when the terminal window is active.

It reappears when it's not active, but that doesn't matter as it's not getting in the way (it appears in lightened text as the window is not active).

It also only works with the first terminal if you have both vertically and horizontally split terminals, which is an unlikely thing for me to do in gvim.

```
" These options need to be set, which I think make more sense anyway
set splitright
set splitbelow

" Disable statusline in gvim terminal window (when active)
if has('gui_running')
  augroup TerminalStatusline
    autocmd!
    autocmd TerminalOpen * set laststatus=0
    autocmd BufEnter     * if &buftype != 'terminal' | set laststatus=2 | endif
    autocmd BufEnter     * if &buftype == 'terminal' | set laststatus=0 | endif
  augroup END
endif
```

Comment: Well no. 1. That autocommand doesn't do what you asked at all. 2. The check for `buftype` is pointless. 3. The comment doesn't describe what is happening accurately. 4. The status line for the last window is lost once you have closed the terminal window.

Comment: @romainl I have come up with a satisfactory solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: How does `:set laststatus=0` disable the statusline? That cannot work if you have multiple windows open.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Well, it does. It only disables the terminal statusline when the terminal windows is active and nothing else.

Comment: yes, if you only have a single window open, it will disable the statusline, yes that is correct. But that is quite a limiting factor, it does not work in the general case when you have multiple windows open

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I'm not sure what you mean, as I have several windows and even multiple terminals open here and it works fine.

Comment: @paradroid, `laststatus=0` disables the status line of the last window (hence the name). *If your terminal is the last window*, then setting the option to `0` will effectively disable its status line, but, *if the terminal is not the last window*, then its status line will *not* be disabled, another window's will. That's a band-aid, not a solution.

Comment: @romainl I'm experiencing exactly the behaviour that I have described in the answer. Could it be something else in the configuration? I don't know what else I can say about it, as it's working essentially how I wanted it to and I don't see what the problem is. gVim on Linux and Windows.

Comment: `$ vim --clean -o foo bar baz`: https://i.imgur.com/HIYUyK3.png. The current window is the one with `foo`, the terminal window opens above it by default, its status line doesn't change, the status line of the last window is disabled. Not what you are asking at all.

Comment: @romainl It seems to depend on a couple of options which were a two of the earliest options I ever did set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable individual status lines, the `:terminal`'s included.

Furthermore…

1. The events `TermOpen` and `TermClose` don't exist. Instead of trying random events, find the right ones under `:help autocommand-events`:

   ```
             Terminal
    |TerminalOpen|      after a terminal buffer was created
    |TerminalWinOpen|   after a terminal buffer was created in a new window
   ```

   And yes, there is no corresponding "`*Close`" event, which means that your strategy needs a bit of rethinking.
2. Setting `:help 'laststatus'` locally is pointless anyway, because it is a global option. You either have a status line on the last window or you don't, and the terminal's status line is not special.

Comment: Oh, I see. I have another autocmd that uses `TermOpen` to disable a plugin in the terminal as it caused problems (BetterWhiteSpace), but that's for NeoVim. It does exist in NeoVim. I think I managed to get it working with this information.